# How do I report a bug in Blender?

Tags: versions

I have noticed that Blender crashes under certain circumstances. Every time I try to open a separate 3D Window with either Bone or Empty Sphere added to the scene, it just shuts down.

Can you confirm similar behavior? 
If it is a bug, how do I report it?

Blender version 2.69 (sub 2),
build date: 2013-11-07.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Here is the console output:

```
connect failed: No such file or directory  
Read new prefs: /home/orustam/.config/blender/2.69/config/userpref.blend  
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt  
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Contents of the `blender.crash.txt` file:

```
# Blender 2.69 (sub 2), Revision: 61181
bpy.ops.object.armature_add(view_align=True, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 1), 
rotation=(0, -0, 0), 
layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))  # Operator

# backtrace
/usr/lib/blender/blender() [0xbf87d2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x364a0) [0x7f1c9820c4a0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdricore9.0.3.so.1(vbo_save_playback_vertex_list+0x42) [0x7f1c863c9ee2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdricore9.0.3.so.1(+0x7e592) [0x7f1c862f4592]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdricore9.0.3.so.1(_mesa_CallList+0x82) [0x7f1c862f8362]
/usr/lib/blender/blender() [0xcdb942]
/usr/lib/blender/blender() [0xcdc776]
/usr/lib/blender/blender() [0xcde730]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(draw_armature+0x93a) [0xce011a]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(draw_object+0x3ea6) [0xcd4926]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(view3d_main_area_draw+0x697) [0xca56f7]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(ED_region_do_draw+0x85d) [0xe6e1ed]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(wm_draw_update+0x5bb) [0xbfcc4b]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(WM_main+0x28) [0xbf9b78]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(main+0xcbf) [0xbc2c0f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7f1c981f776d]
/usr/lib/blender/blender() [0xbf72e9]
```

Comment: [Here is a nice article/video](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/09/29/reporting-bugs-in-blender/) by Sebastian König about reporting bugs in Blender.

Comment: I also found a problem yesterday with a separated 3D window... In my case the window opened and worked properly, but if I tried to render (hit F12) from this window, Blender crashed. However, I'm not sure if Blender.SE is the right place to discuss about bugs...